# Sending email in html format

Tags: php, joomla

Hi I am configuring a Joomla Application for sending emails using gmail smtp server. I used it on my localhost and found to work correctly. But its not working on my remote host server. I am using the same settings for it. Can anyone reply me the problem. Its says that email could not be sent

Answer (score 0):

Did you sent bulk mails, news letter and etc ?

if the answer is "yes", you should check your gmail account, because gmail smtp server has a smart bulk spamer recognition engine. so they may deactivated your smtp account because of sending about more than even 50 mails in last 10 mins.

so my suggestion is to forget gmail as your smtp server and start your own smtp server or buy a paid smtp account to do this.

Comment: I am not using it to send bulk mails. Its used just to send articles in email format. It works corretcly with my localhost but not my remote host

Comment: some hosting providers close their default outgoing smtp port (25)

in this case you should try the other smtp port witch is supported by google mail too : **587** 

try this port for your outgoing smtp. if your authentication info was correct, every this should go right.

Comment: Just change your connection port to your smtp server to 587
do you have any log record about your mail sender result ?